# RTL Bootstrap TAB

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day, 
i need to show the tabs from RTL. currently the order as you can see on this example is LTR Our Story , Mission, Our Activity, FAQ
it should be same order but RTL 
FAQ, Our Activity, Mission, Our Story

```css
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav > li.disabled > a {
  color: #e4eaec;
}

.nav > li.disabled > a:hover,
.nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #e4eaec;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #5d9cec;
}

.nav .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9.5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.nav > li > a > img {
  max-width: none;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #dddddd #dddddd #dddddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #dde6e9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }

  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }

  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #f5f7fa;
  }
}

.nav-pills > li {
  float: right;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5d9cec;
}

.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-justified > li > a {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }

  .nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs-justified > li > a {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a,
.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }

  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a,
  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #f5f7fa;
  }
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: right;
  }
}

.navbar-collapse {
  overflow-x: visible;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }

  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }

  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#story" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Our Story</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#mission" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#activity" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Our Activity</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#faq" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FAQ</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: does 
  direction:rtl; ansers to your question or did you mean something else ? demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epBBLQ

Comment: perfect. this is what i was looking for. thank you very much.